# Google Apps Script (MailApp Class / sendEmail Method) - Sending from Shared Mailbox

Tags: google-apps-script

I've got a working Sheets / Google Code script to pull information from a sheet and fire it into a HTML templated e-mail but was wondering if there's any way you can define the senders address beyond the user you're authenticated to.

i.e. User is authenticated into G-Suite and has access to shared mailboxes. Is there a way of defining which mailbox to send from via Google Apps Script?

Couldn't see any documentation on this so hold limited hopes but wanted to check with the community at SO before closing it off.

Google documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app

Thanks

Comment: Is the shared mailbox an alias?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `GmailApp` instead, you can select one of your available aliases using [`sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient-subject-body-options).

For example:

```
GmailApp.sendEmail("recipient@example.com", "Subject", "Body", {from: "alias@example.com"});
```

Note that to do so, the `from` address must be an available alias. You can check available aliases with this function:

```
function listAliases() {
  var me = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var aliases = GmailApp.getAliases();
  Logger.log(aliases);
}
```

Comment: Awesome thanks very much for identifying this for me!